# Numpy array with coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with a column with different coordinates, clustered together in other lists, like this:

```
    name    OBJECTID    geometry
0    NaN           1    ['-80.304852,-3.489302,0.0','-80.303087,-3.490214,0.0',...]

1    NaN           2    ['-80.27494,-3.496571,0.0',...]

2    NaN           3    ['-80.267987,-3.500003,0.0',...]
```

I want to separate the values and remove the '0.0', but keep them inside the lists to add them to a certain key in a dictionary, that looks like this:

```
    name    OBJECTID    geometry
0    NaN           1    [[-80.304852, -3.489302],[-80.303087, -3.490214],...]

1    NaN           2    [[-80.27494, -3.496571],...]

2    NaN           3    [[-80.267987, -3.500003],...]
```

This is my code that didn't work where I tried to separate them in a for loop:

```
import panda as pd
import numpy as np

r = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
rloc = np.asarray(r['geometry'])

r['latitude'] = np.zeros(r.shape[0],dtype= r['geometry'].dtype)
r['longitude'] = np.zeros(r.shape[0],dtype= r['geometry'].dtype)

# Separating the latitude and longitude values form each string.
for i in range(0, len(rloc)):
    for j in range(0, len(rloc[i])):
        coord = rloc[i][j].split(',')
        r['longitude'] = coord[0]
        r['latitude'] = coord[1]

r = r[['OBJECTID', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'name']]
```

Edit: The result wasn't good because it printed out only one value for each one.

```
  OBJECTID  latitude    longitude   name
0        1  -3.465566   -80.151633  NaN
1        2  -3.465566   -80.151633  NaN
2        3  -3.465566   -80.151633  NaN
```

Bonus question: How cand I add all of these longitude and latitude values inside a tuple to use with geopy? Like this:

```
r['location'] = (r['latitude], r['longitude'])
```

So, instead, the geometry column would look like this:

```
geometry
[(-80.304852, -3.489302),(-80.303087, -3.490214),...]

[(-80.27494, -3.496571),...]

[(-80.267987, -3.500003),...]
```

Edit:

The data looked like this at first(for each row):

```
<LineString><coordinates>-80.304852,-3.489302,0.0 -80.303087,-3.490214,0.0 ...</coordinates></LineString>
```

I modified it with regex, using this code:

```
geo = np.asarray(r['geometry']); 
geo = [re.sub(re.compile('<.*?>'), '', string) for string in geo]
```

And then I placed it in an array:

```
rv = [geo[i].split() for i in range(0,len(geo))]
r['geometry'] = np.asarray(rv)
```

When I call r['geometry'], the output is:

```
0    [-80.304852,-3.489302,0.0, -80.303087,-3.49021...
1    [-80.27494,-3.496571,0.0, -80.271963,-3.49266,...
2    [-80.267987,-3.500003,0.0, -80.267845,-3.49789...
Name: geometry, dtype: object
```

And `r['geometry'][0]` is:

```
 ['-80.304852,-3.489302,0.0',
 '-80.303087,-3.490214,0.0',
 '-80.302131,-3.491878,0.0',
 '-80.300763,-3.49213,0.0']
```

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: Updated with the result! It doesn't work because the list that's inside is removed... I'm trying to find a way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pandas solution with input from a toy data set:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt")
   name  OBJECTID                                           geometry
0   NaN         1  ['-80.3,-3.4,0.0','-80.3,-3.9,0.0','-80.3,-3.9...
1   NaN         2  ['80.2,-4.4,0.0','-81.3,2.9,0.0','-80.7,-3.2,0...
2   NaN         3  ['-80.1,-3.2,0.0','-80.8,-2.9,0.0','-80.1,-1.9...
```

Now the transformation into columns of longitude-latitude pairs:

```
#regex extraction of longitude latitude pairs
pairs = "(-?\d+.\d+,-?\d+.\d+)"
s = df["geometry"].str.extractall(pairs)
#splitting string into two parts, creating two columns for longitude latitude
s = s[0].str.split(",", expand = True)  
#converting strings into float numbers - is this even necessary?
s[[0, 1]] = s[[0, 1]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
#creating a tuple from longitude/latitude columns
s["lat_long"] = list(zip(s[0], s[1]))
#placing the tuples as columns in original dataframe 
df = pd.concat([df, s["lat_long"].unstack(level = -1)], axis = 1)
```

Output from the toy data set:

```
   name  OBJECTID                                           geometry  \
0   NaN         1  ['-80.3,-3.4,0.0','-80.3,-3.9,0.0','-80.3,-3.9...   
1   NaN         2  ['80.2,-4.4,0.0','-81.3,2.9,0.0','-80.7,-3.2,0...   
2   NaN         3  ['-80.1,-3.2,0.0','-80.8,-2.9,0.0','-80.1,-1.9...   

               0              1              2  
0  (-80.3, -3.4)  (-80.3, -3.9)  (-80.3, -3.9)  
1   (80.2, -4.4)   (-81.3, 2.9)  (-80.7, -3.2)  
2  (-80.1, -3.2)  (-80.8, -2.9)  (-80.1, -1.9)
```

Alternatively, you can combine the tuples in one column as a list:

```
s["lat_long"] = list(zip(s[0], s[1]))
#placing the tuples as a list into a column of the original dataframe 
df["lat_long"] = s.groupby(level=[0])["lat_long"].apply(list)
```

Output now:

```
   name  OBJECTID                                           geometry  \
0   NaN         1  ['-80.3,-3.4,0.0','-80.3,-3.9,0.0','-80.3,-3.9...   
1   NaN         2  ['80.2,-4.4,0.0','-81.3,2.9,0.0','-80.7,-3.2,0...   
2   NaN         3  ['-80.1,-3.2,0.0','-80.8,-2.9,0.0','-80.1,-1.9...   

                                        lat_long  
0  [(-80.3, -3.4), (-80.3, -3.9), (-80.3, -3.9)]  
1    [(80.2, -4.4), (-81.3, 2.9), (-80.7, -3.2)]  
2  [(-80.1, -3.2), (-80.8, -2.9), (-80.1, -1.9)]
```

Comment: It seems like the list 's' is empty. The line 's = df["geometry"].str.extractall(pairs)' is not doing anything and if I try to print s out, I only get an empty dataframe with 0 as the column name.

Comment: You always should provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I worked with the information given here, but seemingly, the field geometry differs from your description. Can you upload a sample file and describe how you create the dataframe, so I can adapt the script?

Comment: Updated post with new example.

Comment: Is it possible that `df['geometry'].str.extractall(pairs)` doesn't work because the dtype is 'object'?

Comment: Here is the [data](https://ufile.io/7dndp). The other details about how I processed it are in the post.

Comment: Ok. I removed the other code where I processed the 'geometry' column and it works fine now! Also, I tried to remove the None value from each array using `s = s[s != np.array(None)]` , but after that it returns NaN... I need to compare each tuple to one in another dictionary so I can't have any None or NaN data inside, as it will produce an error. Any way around that?

Comment: I updated the code, it works now with unequal lengths, too. The solution comes from [Wen, please give him an upvote for his contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750871/8881141).

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are effectively assigning the longitude and latitude values of last iteration to the complete columns. You may also convert string to float:

```
# Separating the latitude and longitude values form each string.
for i in range(0, len(rloc)):
    r['longitude'][i] = []
    r['latitude'][i] = []
    for j in range(0, len(rloc[i])):
        coord = rloc[i][j].split(',')
        r['longitude'][i].append(float(coord[0]))
        r['latitude'][i].append(float(coord[1]))
```

Going for the bonus :)

```
for i in range(0, len(rloc)):
    r['geometry'][i] = [
        (
            float(element.split(',')[0]),
            float(element.split(',')[1])
        ) for element in r['geometry'][i]
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I chose the other one as the answer because it's much more computationally efficient as I have over one million entries to porcess.