# Pandas - flattening a multiindex column containing tuples, but ignore missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex pandas dataframe like this:

```
lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12), (13, 14), (21, 22)]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['1','2', '3', '4']])).loc[:('B', '2')]
df["tuple"] = list(zip(df[0], df[1]))

#df:
      0   1     tuple
A 1   1   2    (1, 2)
  2   3   4    (3, 4)
  3   5   6    (5, 6)
  4   7   8    (7, 8)
B 1   9  10   (9, 10)
  2  11  12  (11, 12)
```

I want to transform the column, containing the tuples, into a list of tuples. My approach is:

```
#dataframe to append list of tuples
new_df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2], index = list("AB") )

#voila a list of tuples
new_df["list_of_tuples"] = df["tuple"].unstack(level = -1).values.tolist()

#new_df:
   0                 list_of_tuples
A  1     [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
B  2  [(9, 10), (11, 12), None, None]
```

This works, but only for multiindex dataframes with equal length for each entry. If all entries don't have the same length, the missing columns give rise to a `None` value in the list. My attempts to remove numpy `NaN` values, before creating a list, failed. Is there an approach to prevent the appearance of `None` in the final list of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.groupby(level=[0]).tuple.apply(list)
Out[306]: 
A    [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
B                 [(9, 10), (11, 12)]
Name: tuple, dtype: object
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Your approach works on my toy data set here. But though the real dataframe has exactly the same structure (at least, I thought it has), it returns 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'tuple'. Any idea, what the invisible difference could be? The only difference I can think of: My original multiindex dataframe was created by a `str.extractall(pairs)` operation.

Comment: @Piinthesky  `df.groupby(level=[0])['tuple'].apply(list)` try this

Comment: Bingo! I guess, I should put some effort into it and try to understand, how the `groupby()` mapper works. My feeble attempts all failed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Piinthesky yw~ :-) one tips , maybe do not name para with pandas build in function name , such as sum , max, tuple , list ,dict ,etc. If so , you need to call it by using df['Name'] rather than df.Name (Which is more easy to call ) :-) happy coding

Comment: Oops, no, this was just used to illustrate the example. The real dataframe column has a totally different name, nothing to do with pandas built-in functions.

Comment: @Piinthesky great :-) happy coding